# Case-classes and its default constructors

Tags: scala, akka, typechecking

Suppose, I defined the case class:

```
case class A(id: Int)
```

Then I suddenly typed this code:

```
val a = A
```

The question is - why compiler allows such writings? In Java, defining constructor with any parameters, makes the default constructor not available.

EDIT:
Ok, as Ende Neu pointed, the `a` now contains `A.type`. 
How can I avoid scenario, when suddenly typing `a = A` may break my code in:

```
a match {
   case A(id) => do something
   case _ => I didn't expect fall into here
}
```

I'm trying to avoid to fall into the second case in my Akka message processing code. Is it possible?

UPDATE: After some time spent on working with Akka + Scala I figured out, the answer to the second part of this question. Actor's `receive` method has signature `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]`, that means there's no typecheck for the input parameter. So any type is accepted, including `A.type`. Best advice to the user in this context: be careful when sending the messages to actors.

Comment: You should ask a separate question related to your edit. That seems to be something specific to Akka.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are assigning `A.type` to `a`:

```
scala> case class A(id: Int)
defined class A

scala> val a = A
a: A.type = A

scala> a()
<console>:11: error: not enough arguments for method apply: (id: Int)A in object A.
Unspecified value parameter id.
            a()
             ^

scala> a(1)
res1: A = A(1)
```

After the assignment `a` is of type `A.type`, then you can use `a` to construct new instances of the case class `A`, but you will still need to specify the `id` parameter.

Regarding your edit:

```
a match {
  case A(id) => do something
  case _ => I didn't expect fall into here
}
```

I think this correctly throws an exception in this case since you wanted a variable of type `A` and instead you ended up with a variable of type `A.type`, which is most probably a mistake, if you really want to differentiate between `A` and `A.type` in your match something like this should work:

```
scala>  val a = A
a: A.type = A

scala>  a match {
     |    case a: A.type => "A.type"
     |    case someA: A => "case class"
     |    case _ => "default"
     |  }
<console>:13: warning: fruitless type test: a value of type A.type cannot also be a A
                    case someA: A => "case class"
                            ^
<console>:13: warning: unreachable code
                    case someA: A => "case class"
                                 ^
res8: String = A.type

scala> val someA = A(1)
someA: A = A(1)

scala>  someA match {
     |    case a: A.type => "A.type"
     |    case someA: A => "case class"
     |    case _ => "default"
     |  }
<console>:12: warning: fruitless type test: a value of type A cannot also be a A.type
                    case a: A.type => "A.type"
                         ^
res9: String = case class
```

But as I said, this feels weird, probably there's a better solution to this kind of problems that I don't know.

Comment: I appreciate your exhaustive answer. Looks like my second part of question should be in another thread, since it's really is Akka-specific (sending the message like `recipient ! A` breaks my code).

Comment: Yes I think so too, my answer is only related to types and since I don't know that much of `Akka`, I can't help you when you send a type variable instead of an instance as an akka message.

Answer (score 1):

`val a: A = A` will tell you that you're wrong.

There are lots of places you don't leave it up to type inference.

In a local block, which is small by definition or I guess construction, you can reason about the types.

If your `a` is a member, it should always be type-ascribed.

You should never have to say, A long time later, in a distant part of the code, I discovered that an inferred type was totally wrong.